# Перехват и фильтрация программных активностей

Tags: c, windows, драйвер

Хочу реализовать свой драйвер. При установке Windows Driver Kit (WDK) предлагаются шаблоны для написания своего фильтра файловой системы (через `FltRegisterFilter`) и фильтр интернет пакетов (через `NdisFRegisterFilterDriver`).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, (желательно с примерами) как можно перехватывать:

1. чтение/запись в реестр Windows;
2. запуск одного приложения из другого.